# Error in command line “deno run server.ts” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, deno

**controllers/products.ts**

```
import { Product } from "../types.ts";


let products: Product[] = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "Product One",
        description: "This is product one",
        price: 29.99,
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "Product Two",
        description: "This is product two",
        price: 39.99,
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        name: "Product Three",
        description: "This is product three",
        price: 59.99,
    },
];

export const getProducts = ({ response }: { response: any }) => {
    response.body = {
        success: true,
        data: products
    }
}
```

**routes.ts**

```
import { Router } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";
import { getProducts } from "./controllers/products.ts";

const router = new Router()

router.get('/api/v1/products', getProducts)

export default router;
```

**server.ts**

```
import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";
import router from './routes.ts';

const app = new Application()
console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:5000`);

app.use(router.routes())
app.use(router.allowedMethods())

await app.listen({ port: 5000 })
```

I have been tryin to run file *server.ts* with command from command line

```
deno run --allow-net server.ts
```

All I have been getting is error in command line

```
fish: “deno run server.ts” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

Everyting was working fine. Just all of a sudden started not work

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: can't reproduce, what OS and what Deno version are you using?

Comment: **DENO** deno 1.0.1
v8 8.4.300
typescript 3.9.2 **OS** Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

Comment: @RadisavSavkovic I copied your exact code but it runs fine. I also run Ubuntu 20.04 and have Deno 1.0.1.

Comment: @Radisav did you try running simple `app.js` file to see what happens? At what point your script starts to break?

Comment: FYI, I removed the `fish` tag because the question has nothing to do with the fish shell.

Comment: After I restarted the computer everything is working just fine. Because of **Deno** is new runtime I will leave question open for some better solution of this problem.